# How do I avoid this NullPointerException in my custom linked list class?

Tags: java, linked-list, nullpointerexception

I am designing a non-static void method called unlinkNode that takes a Node n as a parameter.  It should ensure that the node is unlinked from the nodes before and after it. It needs to change the prev of the node after n and the next of the node before n. Currently when I run it I get the error

```
[ ERROR    ] exception in unit test code!
java.lang.
NullPointerException
    at LinkedList.unlinkNode(LinkedList.java:111)
    at UNITTEST.test_default(UNITTEST.java:19)
    at UNITTEST.main(UNITTEST.java:81)
```

Line 111 is  n.getPrev().next = null;

Even though I have put in `if` statements to make sure that if n is the tail, not to access its prev, and if its head, not to access its next, to make sure nothing null is being accessed.

Here's the method:

```
public void unlinkNode(Node n) {
    if(head != n && head != null) {
        n.getNext().prev = null;
    }
    if (tail != n && tail != null) {
        n.getPrev().next = null;
    }
}
```

And the code that sets everything up

```
public class LinkedList {
    public static class Node{
        String key;
        int value;
        Node next;
        Node prev;

        public Node(String key, int value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public Node getPrev() {
            return prev;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;

    public LinkedList() {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    public Node getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public Node getTail() {
        return tail;
    }


    public void addHead(String key, int val) {
        Node n = new Node(key, val);

        if(head == null) {
            head = n;
            tail = n;
        } else {
            head.prev = n;
            n.next = head;
            head = n;
        }
    }

    public void addTail(String key, int val) {
        Node n = new Node(key, val);

        if(tail == null) {
            head = n;
            tail = n;
        } else {
            tail.next = n;
            n.prev = tail;
            tail = n;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Either `n` is null or `n.getPrev()` returns null. Have you tried debugging your code (rather than asking others to do it for you) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are assigning null values to them as well, but the checks aren't complete. I would suggest you throw a NullPointerException for you to be able to handle it yourself e.g. inside a try catch block. This will prepare you for scenarios if the values are null then do this instead.

```
try {
   // Your usual code here
} catch(NullPointerException e) {
   // Do something if it hit an NPE
}
```

Comment: Nah ... the real solution is to find the cause of the NPE and fix it.

Comment: Of course. Fix the NPE, but what if he is purposely setting it to null and want to do scenarios when its null? That's why I suggested in my first statement that he should throw an NPE for the class he just made.

Comment: Umm ... the problem is that an *unexpected* NPE is thrown.  From the context, it is not an NPE that the OP would want to occur.  (Look at where it is thrown ...)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that "getPrev" returns null. It's to few code to confirm that. You can't see if "addHead" oder "addTail" is called.

Answer (score 0):

Think the logic through carefully.  Or draw a picture for yourself.

```
if(head != n && head != null) {
    n.getNext().prev = null;
}
```

Assuming that `next`, `prev`, `head` and `tail` have their intuitive meanings, the test `head != n` does not mean that `n` will have a `next`.  It means that `n` will have a `prev`!

Also ... how could `head` possibly be `null` when you are removing a node from the list?  That field will only be `null` if the list is empty, and you won't be removing anything from an empty list.

So the above should probably be:

```
if (head != n) {
    n.getPrev().next = null;
}
```

and apply the same thinking to the next test.

(NB: I can't test it.  If my suggested fix is wrong, please work out what it should be for yourself.  From first principles, like I did.)